# Is it possible to view a list of all objects used in Google Slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

When some objects in Google Slides get hidden behind another object it may be later hard to find them on the slide.
Is it possible, for example, to see a panel with a list of all objects which are present on a given slide? And possibly edit them even if they are in the bottom layer (completely hidden behind another object)? This might be useful for animations when an object is displayed later and fully covers a previously displayed object.

[image]

Comment: About `for example, to see a panel with a list of all objects which are present on a given slide?`, what is `panel` you expect? And, I cannot understand about `And possibly edit them even if they are in the bottom layer (completely hidden behind another object)?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to create an animation of objects in a way that in every step a new rectangle comes in with a different text inside. All the rectangles have the same position on the slide, so they fully overlap each other. Later, when I decide to edit the text in the first rectangle which is at the very bottom layer (the object that is displayed as the first one when I play the slides), I have to first remove all the other overlapping rectangles to get to the very first one, then edit the text in it and move the other rectangles again back to the original position.

Comment: So I was curious if Google Slides can show something like a list of all objects present on the slide where I could easily change their properties and the text without having to actually move the objects back and forth on the slide to be able to see the one I need to modify.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, do you want to change only the text data? Will you also change the text style and the style of text box?

Comment: I usually would like to edit the text only. Do you have any idea how to do it quickly?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your goal I believe is as follows.

- Your Google Slides has several text boxes of the same size and the same position.
- You want to retrieve the list of texts from the text boxes and want to change the texts using a simpler method.

In this case, I thought that when the sidebar created by Google Apps Script is used for changing the texts, your goal might be able to be simply achieved.

The sample script is as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slides and save the script. And then, please reopen the Google Slides. By this, the custom menu "sample" is created for the Google Slides. When "RUN" in the custom menu "sample" is opened, the script is run.

##### Code.gs

Please copy and paste this script as `Code.gs`.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu("sample").addItem("RUN", "openSidebar").addToUi();
}

function openSidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setTitle("sample");
  SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function getSelectedShapes() {
  const select = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  const pageElementRange = select.getPageElementRange();
  if (pageElementRange) {
    const obj = pageElementRange.getPageElements().reduce((ar, e) => {
      if (e.getPageElementType() == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
        const shape = e.asShape();
        ar.push({objectId: shape.getObjectId(), text: shape.getText().asString().trim()});
      }
      return ar;
    }, []).reverse();
    return obj;
  }
  return [];
}

function updatedTexts(o) {
  const select = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  const slide = select.getCurrentPage();
  const obj = slide.getShapes().reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.getObjectId()]: {shape: e, text: e.getText().asString().trim()}}), {});
  o.forEach(({objectId, text}) => {
    if (obj[objectId] && obj[objectId].text != text) {
      obj[objectId].shape.getText().setText(text);
    }
  });
  return "Done";
}
```

##### index.html

Please copy and paste this script as `index.html`.

```html
<input type="button" id="main" value="Get selected shapes" onClick="main()">
<div id="shapes"></div>
<input type="button" id="update" value="Updated texts" onClick="updatedTexts()" style="display:none">
<script>
  function main() {
    document.getElementById("main").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("shapes").innerHTML = "";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(o => {
      if (o.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("update").style.display = "none";
        return;
      }
      const div = document.getElementById("shapes");
      o.forEach(({objectId, text}) => {
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("id", objectId);
        input.setAttribute("value", text);
        div.appendChild(input);
      });
      document.getElementById("update").style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("main").disabled = false;
    }).getSelectedShapes();
  }

  function updatedTexts() {
    const inputs = document.getElementById("shapes").getElementsByTagName('input');
    const obj = [...inputs].map(e => ({objectId: e.id, text: e.value}));
    console.log(obj)
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => console.log(e)).updatedTexts(obj);
  }
</script>
```

#### 2. Testing:

Please reopen Google Slides. By this, the custom menu is created. Please open "sample" -> "RUN". By this, the sidebar is opened.

1. Please select the text boxes on Google Slides.
2. Click "Get selected shapes" button.

   - By this, the selected text boxes are retrieved and you can see the texts of text boxes.
3. Modify the texts.
4. Click "Updated texts" button.

   - By this, the modified texts are reflected in the text boxes.

Also, you can see it with the following demonstration movie.

[image]

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify the above script and HTML style for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)

Comment: This is great, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much you spent your time looking into this.
It works like a charm. I just noticed that if you quickly click the "Get selected shapes" button multiple times, you may get a doubled or tripled list of the selected objects. I just wonder if it's something easy to fix. Although it's something one can easily work around.

Comment: @Jakub Janis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, for example, how about using `disabled` for the input tag when the button is clicked? By this, I think that the continuous click can be prevented. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help!